# Can we extend the basis of a subspace of a tensor product space to the defining tensor product basis of the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{C}\subseteq \mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}}$ which is a subspace of a tensor-product space as so. All bases I refer to are implicitly orthonormal. Choose a basis $\{|i\rangle\}$ of $\mathcal{H}_{C}$ and extend it to a basis $\{|j\rangle\}$ of $\mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}}$. By definition of a tensor product space, we know that one possible basis of $\mathcal{H}_{A}\otimes\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}}$ is $\{|a\overline{a}\rangle\}=\{|a\rangle\otimes|\overline{a}\rangle\}$ where $\{|a\rangle\}$ and $\{|\overline{a}\rangle\}$ are bases of $\mathcal{H}_{A}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\overline{A}}$ respectively.

My question is whether we can **always** choose the basis $\{|i\rangle\}$ in such a way that the basis $\{|j\rangle\}$ we extend it to will be equivalent to the defining $\{|a\overline{a}\rangle\}$ basis. I suppose an alternative phrasing would be whether we can always choose $\{|i\rangle\}$ such that each basis element $|i\rangle$ can be written as a tensor product $|i\rangle=|a\overline{a}\rangle$. My gut says no, but I can't think up a counterexample - a proof evades me too, if it is true. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the relationship between $A$ and $\overline A$? If no relationship then it'd be better to replace $\overline A$ with $B$.

Comment: @WhatsUp This has an application to quantum erasure correction where in context, $\overline{A}$ is an erased subsystem so the notation makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" as long as $A$ and $\overline A$ have dimension larger than $1$, so that there exist non-pure tensors.

For an example, just take any non-pure tensor $v \in A \otimes \overline A$ and let $C$ be the one dimensional subspace generated by $v$. A basis of $C$ is necessarily a constant multiple of $v$, which is not a pure tensor by construction, and hence any extension of that basis contains some non-pure tensor.

(On the existence of non-pure tensors: imagine that $A$ and $\overline A$ are $n$-dimensional spaces, so that $A\otimes \overline A$ can be identified with the space of $n \times n$ matrices. Pure tensors correspond to matrices of rank $\leq 1$, hence as long as $n \geq 2$ there exist non-pure tensors.)